# managing conversational answers

Tags: discussion

I've noticed on a number of questions that people have posted comments or more conversational replies as answers, which feels like its wandering towards a forum feel. How can we nudge these in the right direction ?

Not picking on anyone, but see this question for an example 
[SOAP API Request with body larger than 16 Kilobytes results in Timeout Exception](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/189/soap-api-request-with-body-larger-than-16-kilobytes-results-in-timeout-exception)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solid concern.  I can think of two things.

1. Suggesting/Making edits when appropriate.
2. Downvoting some of the "answers" that aren't really answers along with a comment along the lines of "This isn't really an answer.  Please only post answers to the question as answers".

I like #2, because to me the voting aspect is one of the biggest strengths of the StackExchange model.